# 2k+ flags... 51 useful?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, user-profile, status-murdered

Is something going wrong here? Maybe 51 of my flags were *not* useful?

[image]

Comment: The 51 are the declined/disputed.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with what the profile looks like for non-mods, I'm having a hard time working out what other people can see. Time for a trip to the sock drawer methinks...

Comment: @AshleyNunn are you sure? On my SO profile I got some declined and disputed flags but no number in parenthesis. Wouldn't they be the ones waiting review?

Comment: @jonathan Yeah I am sure. Not sure if seeing it is mod only or not, but it is your declines and disputes. There is no way fredley has 51 flags here waiting review. He's a mod.

Comment: It is mod only then, I'm no mod anywhere! Check my profile on Arqade, you should see 3 while I don't see a thing.

Comment: +1 for status-murdered.

Comment: Re: "I'm not familiar with what the profile looks like for non-mods": Incognito mode is your friend.  Also there are other SE sites :D

Comment: @JohntheGreen Yup, or the trusty sock-drawer!

Comment: 51 useful sounds about right for 2.1k flags from you @fredley ;D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Total number of raised flags marked useful" is the hover text for the entire line, not the (51).

Comment: and the (51) represents the number of declined/disputed flags